# c# dll to detect boxes(textareas) upon previewmousedown in windows

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllimport

hello i would like to know if there is any dll or global hook code out there that would allow me to run an application like on screen keyboard as soon as i click on a textarea.

It would be greatly appreciated, google is not being too friendly to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for an [Input Method Editor (IME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method).